# JHipster 6.0.1: Liquibase tasks fail

Tags: gradle, mariadb, jhipster, liquibase

Just trying out JHipster v6.0.1, following the sample Blog application (http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-mraible/jhipster5-demo//README.adoc). Choosing Gradle as the build tool, with MariaDB in development and production, liquibase tasks fail.

- Install the development environment:

  - Install MariaDB 10.3
  - Install JDK 11 and set environment variables/path accordingly
  - Install node (10.15.3) => npm v6.4.1
  - Install yarn (1.15.2)
  - Launch a shell and, at the command line:

    - Install Yoeman: `npm install -g yo`
    - Install JHipster: `npm install -g generator-jhipster`
- Create a new directory, `blog`, cd into it and type: `jhipster`
- Chose pretty much the same options as in the tutorial linked above, with MariaDB in BOTH development and production, and using Gradle as the build tool.
- Launch the server: `./gradlew`
- Run: `yarn start`

Everything works great.  The database tables get created and populated as expected, and the web application functions well.

Now, when I stop the server, and attempt to run any liquibase task, I get the same error.  For example, running: `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums` on the command line results in:

```
> Task :liquibaseClearChecksums FAILED

During the build, one or more dependencies that were declared without a version failed to resolve:
    org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:

Did you forget to apply the io.spring.dependency-management plugin to the blog project?


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':liquibaseClearChecksums'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibaseRuntime'.
   > Could not find org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

A stacktrace gives a little more information:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibaseRuntime'.
> Could not find org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:.
  Required by:
      project :

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':liquibaseClearChecksums'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibaseRuntime'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: 
Could not find org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:.
Required by:
    project :
```

I get the same outcome on Windows 10 and Linux openSUSE 15.  However, when using Maven, the liquibase tasks work fine.  Is this just me?  Anyone got any ideas as to why?

[JHipster: 6.0.1; JDK11; MariaDB 10.3.14; Node v10.15.3; Yarn v1.15.2; npm v6.9.0; Gradle v5.4.1]

**PS**: Deleted JHipster 6.0.1, then installed v5.8.2 (`npm install -g generator-jhipster@5.8.2`), repeated the process outlined above, and the Gradle liquibase tasks work!  I think this is a bug with the new JHipster 6.0.1 deployment...  Should I/how do I report this to the development team?  Any ideas for a temporary fix?

Also, took the time to compare the `build.gradle` files from the two versions (5.8.2 and 6.0.1); they are quite different, and nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong except: the 5.8.2 version directly references the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin, but the 6.0.1 version does not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay!  I have a solution...

I added the following `+` lines to the `build.gradle` file (starting around line 28):

```
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
+   id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
  }

  sourceCompatibility=1.8
  targetCompatibility=1.8
  assert System.properties["java.specification.version"] == "1.8" || "11" || "12"

  apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
+ apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
  apply plugin: "propdeps"
```

I chose `io.spring.dependency-management` version 1.0.7 because [the Gradle plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management) cites it as the latest version (at the time of writing).

I can now run `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums` with a successful outcome.

Running `./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangeLog` however fails.  Turning on stacktrace, I get the following error:

```
:liquibaseDiffChangeLog FAILED
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'main' activity...
Starting Liquibase at Tue, 21 May 2019 07:16:59 PDT (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: The option --referenceUrl is required.
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: The option --referenceUrl is required.
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(Main.java:1419)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1026)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:199)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137)
```

To resolve this, I copy/paste the `liquibase`/`activities`/`diffLog` `referenceUrl` parameter into the `liquibase`/`activities`/`main` section (see following `+` line):

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      driver "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      url "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/blog"
      username "<username>"
      password "<password>"
      changeLogFile "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml"
      defaultSchemaName ""
      logLevel "debug"
      classpath "src/main/resources/"
+     referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:org.jhipster.blog.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
    }
```

I can now run `./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangeLog` with a successful outcome.  With these changes, I tested both liquibase tasks on Linux and Windows 10 with success.

Am I the only person to notice this?  Did the JHipster team not notice this?  Is JHipster/Gradle/liquibase configuration not being tested?  Is my fix a complete solution?

Could someone experienced with the JHipster/Gradle/liquibase configuration provide some insight/confirmation...?

Comment: Just following up: The new version of JHipster (6.1.0) still suffers from this issue!

Comment: New version of JHipster (6.1.1) still suffers from this issue!  Are JHipster/Gradle/MariaDB/liquibase tasks not supported/tested in JHipster?  Am I the only person to notice this? **PS:** The above changes still work, and with the latest version of io.spring.dependency-management (1.0.8.RELEASE)  @PascalGrimaud

Comment: JHipster 6.1.2 still suffers from this issue. @pascal-grimaud

Comment: JHipster 6.2.0 still suffers from this issue. @pascal-grimaud (Above solution still seems to resolve it.)

Comment: you might want to raise an issue in the appropriate git-repo https://github.com/jhipster instead of commenting here

Comment: JHipster 6.3.0 still suffers from this issue. @pascal-grimaud (Above solution still seems to resolve it.)

Comment: JHipster 6.3.1 still suffers from this issue. @pascal-grimaud (Above solution still seems to resolve it.)

Comment: Okay!  An interesting development... I just tested the new v6.4.1 release, and `liquibaseClearChecksums` _appears_ to work 'out of the box' (i.e. you don't need to add any references to `io.spring.dependency-management`), **but** `liquibaseDiffChangeLog` STILL requires you to copy/paste the `liquibase`/`activities`/`diffLog` `referenceUrl` parameter into the `liquibase`/`activities`/`main` section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and disable the "cacheProvider no" cache.
When you run the app there is another problem with the second level cache and I think it's because of the DB driver.
I hope help you!

Comment: Marco! Thanks for the response/suggestion.  I repeated the whole project again, this time when asked: "Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction?", I answered "No" (thereby disabling the 2nd level cache). After a full build/run (without problems), the liquibase tasks still fail for the same reason noted in my post, on all platforms.  (Nice idea about the DB driver, but in my case I can't imagine how the DB driver would affect things when everything works with Maven.  I suspect something is missing in the Gradle configuration...)